# Can't get all characters displayed in vim

Tags: macos, vim, encoding, ubuntu, locale

I can't get certain characters, like ’ and ‘, to display properly in vim. They show up like `<?>@~X`. They work fine on SnowLeopard, but not on Ubuntu 10.10. The vim config is mirrored on the two systems, and contains:
`set fileencoding=utf-8`
    `set encoding=utf-8`
    `set termencoding=utf-8`
The ’ ‘ signs work in my terminal on ubuntu. Vim on ubuntu is version 7.3 p112, Vim on osx is 7.2 p108.

Any suggestions?
Am I missing anything in my config?

tx,
-aktiv

Answer (score 0):

I have tried an unchanged vim on Ubuntu 10.04 and both of ticks are displayed as expected. The version I have tried was 7.2.330. If it helps, I can try 10.10 later, too.

Some remarks to track the problem down:

- Debian/Ubuntu is completely UTF-8 based/aware for some time now. So there is no need to set it on your own, but it should not hurt, too.
- For example the back tick (`) is an ASCII character and should "always" be available. It is an important character, e.g. for Shell or Perl programming.

So I do not expect that you are **missing** something in your configuration. Quite the opposite:

- Perhaps you have added something in your configuration that treats the back tick special, e.g. tries to change the color or something like that.
- So I would like to suggest, that you remove your custom configuration from the system and tries if the ticks and other characters are working. If this is the case you can add some of the configurations again. At some point the ticks should stop working. Then you have a small number of customizations that make these ugly characters.